# Why are the first inode of the `/` mounted partition and inode of `/` different?

Tags: linux, filesystems, inode, root-filesystem, vfs

```
[~]$ stat -c %i /
2
```

As you can see in above, the `inode` for `/` is 2. But the `First inode` of `/dev/sda2` is 11.

```
[~]$ df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2             350G   67G  266G  21% /
tmpfs                  12G   44M   12G   1% /dev/shm

[~]$ sudo tune2fs -l /dev/sda2  | grep 'First inode'
First inode:              11
```

Can any one help me to understand this difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value in the superblock shown by tune2fs is the first inode number usable for *new* files, while the root directory must always exist when the file system is created.

[The kernel’s Ext4 documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/filesystems/ext4/overview.html#special-inodes) lists the inode numbers which are used internally by file systems features.